# Multi Client video tcp stream intel realsense

Tags: multithreading, tcp, stream, point-clouds, realsense

The intel - real sense camera provides two video streams at once, a rgb as well as a depth stream. I now need to make those two streams separately accessible locally over a server for multiple clients. I found ways to do that for only rgb and and a single client, but could not find a guide for a multi stream - multi client solution in Python.
I did my research but could not quite find what I needed. If anyone could point me to a/multiple tutorials or generally tools I should use, that would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

How about [ROS wrapper of realsense](https://github.com/IntelRealSense/realsense-ros). 
Realsensen camera will be wrapped inside a ROS node. Then it will publish color, depth frame into seperated message queues. Finally, you can subcribe to those message queues to get the frame.

[image: ros topic]
([Image source](https://roboticsbackend.com/what-is-a-ros-topic/#Multiple_publishers_for_one_topic))